# General development issue saving files with file id in filename (Applied in Symfony2)

Tags: php, file, symfony, save

I have a Symfony2 application with a Person entity, and photo entity. People can have many photos. The photos entity has, among other properties, an ID property, a Person property (stored as person id), and a filename property.

My preferred naming convention for photo files is [person_id]_[photo_id].ext.

This causes an issue, however, in that I now need to persist files to the database twice...once to get the id, then again after the file is saved so I can save the filename with the IDs that I now have.

The only three solutions I can think of are:

1. Abandon this naming convention (not optimal)
2. Save the entity twice (Also not optimal, what I'm doing at the moment)
3. Don't save the filepath in the database, instead calculate it from the id and     person_id every time the entity is loaded.

3 is the only solution that doesn't cause any real issues, but it really feels like the wrong approach...am I just having separation anxiety with my "filename" property?

I'm mostly just open to how other people feel about this issue, thanks a bunch.

Comment: Are you using Doctrine or Propel? Or something else?

Comment: Doctrine. Being able to hook into lifeCycle callbacks would definitely be a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is with Propel, not Doctrine, but based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172967/doctrine2-insert-and-retrieve-new-insert-id) about getting inserted IDs, it seems you may not be able to avoid the extra call.

What I do for filenames when people submit files is to use a cleaned up version of the name that they submitted for it, combined with a timestamp. This is option 1 on your list. You could calculate them dynamically, but that adds a limitation to your data model you may not want.

Basically, my filenames look like `20131126115943-example.png`, instead of `1_1.png`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend sticking with #2, since the impact should only be several milliseconds. You will always need to save the record to the database first to get the ID, assuming the ID is automatically generated.

If performance dictates you absolutely cannot save the entity twice, I'd recommend generating a unique token for your entity prior to saving (timestamp is fine), and using that in the filename.