# Get last inserted ID from doctrine and native mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using doctrine in symfony2. But I used native mysql query to insert some data. Now I want the last inserted id from the database. My code looks like:

```
$stmt = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
             ->getConnection()
             ->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_company (v1,v2,v3) values('$v1','$v2','$v3')");
$stmt->execute();
```

So to recover the last inserted id I tried

```
$stmt->insert_id; 

$id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)

$id=$stmt->getId();
```

and many other. None of them worked for me. I'm new to doctrine. **How to get the last inserted ID from here?** What I'm missing?

Comment: check the link you will get your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172967/doctrine2-insert-and-retrieve-new-insert-id

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
$conn = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();

$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO tb_company (v1, v2, v3) values(:v1, :v2, :v3)');
$stmt->bindValue('v1', $v1);
$stmt->bindValue('v2', $v2);
$stmt->bindValue('v3', $v3);
$stmt->execute();

$id = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

You can't chain the `bindValue`'s or the `execute` because they return a `boolean`

Comment: Today is the day. 31-12-13 is the day bro when you saved my life. Thank you :)

Comment: @AtanuCSE even if lastInsertId() is a good solution(connection specific) but this is a better [solution(first one with orm)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7173364/1363495) in my view

Comment: @GunnerAziz I agree 100% that if you're going to use Doctrine, you should use the ORM as well. However, he stated: _I'm using doctrine in symfony2. But I used native mysql query to insert some data. Now I want the last inserted id from the database._ I don't know why he wants to do a native query, nor do I care. :)

Comment: Another life saved