# Doctrine migrations: how to retrieve value right after insert

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a doctrine migration class with standard up method, like this:

```
$this->addSql("INSERT INTO `mytable` (`name`) VALUES ('myvalue')");

        $res = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('a')
            ->from(MyEntityClass::class, 'a')
            ->where("a.name = :name")
            ->setParameter('name', 'myvalue')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
        $id = $res[0]->getId();

        //some other operation using $id...
```

running this code I got an error: Notice: Undefined offset: 0

if I manually check the db, the value was not inserted.

However, if I commented out the block with the select query, the value is correctly saved to the table.

Looks to me the query in addSql are all executed at the end of the script, is there a way to retrieve a value right after it was saved on the db?

Comment: It seems like you could use Doctrine to create the item instead of a pure query, then get the id from what was created.

Comment: I think its a duplicate - check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20852352/1275737)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `addSql` is not executed immediately.
Try to do the following:

```
$this->connection->executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `mytable` (`name`) VALUES ('myvalue')");
// and then
$lastId = $this->connection->fetchColumn('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');
```

P.S. And don't use query builder inside migrations(it's a bad practice). Because your entity can be changed in the future(or even removed).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [source code of `addSql`](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/blob/3.2.x/lib/Doctrine/Migrations/AbstractMigration.php#L143), it does not execute any statement, but puts it into an array of statements that are executed later. That's why you cannot access the ID directly.

You could read that ID within any other statement through a subquery, like:

```php
$this->addSql('INSERT INTO otherTable(x,y)
    VALUES(1, (SELECT id from mytable WHERE `name` = "myvalue"))'
);
```